# How to animate camera.lookAt using gsap?

Tags: three.js, gsap

camera.lookAt(myObject) will instantly rotate the three.js camera towards the given object.

I would like to animate this rotation using gsap. I have no problem using gsap to animate a change in camera position, but the camera rotation code below does nothing.

```
const targetOrientation = myObject.quaternion.normalize();
gsap.to({}, {
    duration: 2,
    onUpdate: function() {
        controls.update();
        camera.quaternion.slerp(targetOrientation, this.progress());
    }
});
```

How can I animate a camera rotation in this way?

OK this is now fixed. The main problem was a controls.update() line in my render() function. Orbit controls do not work well with camera rotation so you need to make sure that they are completely disabled during the animation.

My revised code that includes rotation and position animations:

```
const camrot = {'x':camera.rotation.x,'y':camera.rotation.y,'z':camera.rotation.z}
camera.lookAt(mesh.position);
const targetOrientation = camera.quaternion.clone().normalize();

camera.rotation.x = camrot.x;
camera.rotation.y = camrot.y;
camera.rotation.z = camrot.z;

const aabb = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mesh );
const center = aabb.getCenter( new THREE.Vector3() );
const size = aabb.getSize( new THREE.Vector3() );

controls.enabled = false;   

const startOrientation = camera.quaternion.clone();

gsap.to({}, {
    duration: 2,
    onUpdate: function() {
        camera.quaternion.copy(startOrientation).slerp(targetOrientation, this.progress());
    },
    onComplete: function() {
        gsap.to( camera.position, {
            duration: 8,
            x: center.x,
            y: center.y,
            z: center.z+4*size.z,
            onUpdate: function() {
                camera.lookAt( center );
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                controls.enabled = true;
                controls.target.set( center.x,  center.y, center.z);
            }
        } );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like so:

```js
let mesh, renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 20, 10, 20 );
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    // ambient
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
    
    // light
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    light.position.set( 20,20, 0 );
    scene.add( light );
    
    // axes
    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper( 20 ) );

    // geometry
    const geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 5, 12, 8 );
    
    // material
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0x00ffff, 
        flatShading: true,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.7,
    } );
    
    // mesh
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
        
    const startOrientation = camera.quaternion.clone();
    const targetOrientation = mesh.quaternion.clone().normalize();
        
    gsap.to( {}, {
        duration: 2,
        onUpdate: function() {
            camera.quaternion.copy(startOrientation).slerp(targetOrientation, this.progress());
        }
    } );
    
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.4.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

You have to ensure to call `Quaternion.slerp()` always with the start orientation and not with `camera.quaternion`. Otherwise the interpolation will be incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful example. Unfortunately when I use your code in my application, I still get no response when attempting to animate camera rotations (camera position animations are fine). It is interesting to see that the same code is working here. I am using orbit controls. I did try controls.enabled = false; but it made no difference.

Comment: I will try to remove parts of my other code to see if I can get it working.

Comment: Even removing the orbit controls makes no difference. Will try running your exact code on my server.

Comment: OK, now I see the problem I think. When I log the results in my code, targetOrientation == sourceOrientation. So the camera does not rotate. I think that the issue is that targetOrientation needs to be the angle between where the camera is currently looking and where it would be looking if it was looking at the mesh. Does that make sense?

Comment: What I did was point the camera to the target, get the quaternion, and then point it back to the original position. That way  targetOrientation != sourceOrientation. But when I run your code there is still no animation.

Comment: It's best if you show what you are doing with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: OK, fixed. My code is too large for a full live example right now but I will put it up in GitHub in a week or two. For now, the problem was a controls.update() line in my render() function. Camera rotation does not work well with Orbit controls so you need to make sure that they are not in use during the entire render while the animation is under way. Will update the OP post.