# Smooth tranzition between camera points of view

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am trying to make a smooth transition between the different points of view of the camera (i made a cube for each point of view). The transition i am using is working at the moment but only for once, after which whenever a button is pressed it just jumps to the pointed cube with no transition. What i am looking for is an actual transition that can go smoothly to each cube (so if i want to go from top-left arrow to bottom-right arrow it should smoothly transition from the point we are at right now and not from a set point).

The code is kind of long but it is basically the same thing repeated for all 9 buttons(which is probably not the best practice).

https://jsfiddle.net/z9v3jwnk/

```
var aabb = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(cube);
var center = aabb.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
var size = aabb.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());

document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", but);

function but() {
  gsap.to(camera.position, {
    duration: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0,
    onUpdate: function () {
      camera.lookAt(center);
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the transitions after the first one are going to the same camera position, `{x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}` which I think is why you’re not seeing the camera tweening.

I tried changing the destination position on a couple of buttons and I’m seeing transitions: https://jsfiddle.net/2x1d4kzv/1/

Re: best practice - yes your code could definitely be a lot [DRYer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Comment: Well you are right, if i modify the camera position i get a transition but not the transition i am looking for. I'd like the transition to happen on what the camera is looking at, so the camera's position stays the same (which is why i set 0,0,0 for all) but it changes it's focal point. So it's like a circle, camera in the middle and you can have a transition around (towards any pressed arrow/cube).

Comment: Ah, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012960/how-to-animate-camera-lookat-using-gsap

Comment: I don’t have specific three.js experience but an approach you might take would be to create a target object which tweens between each centre when the buttons are clicked. Then make the camera always lookAt the target, and make the target invisible.

Comment: That's exactly what i was thinking about, but it seemed too weird at first. I tried implementing it with only 2 buttons(left and right one) for simplification, but i can only jump to the next place, and not have it go smoothly. I set the increment value of time to +=0.01 but as it executes  it just jumps to the next position. https://jsfiddle.net/e3r57afh/4/ . Any idea on how to gradually increment time variable so it goes off in a matter of time(so it increases 0.01 every 0.01s)?

Comment: The js in that fiddle is a bit muddled and I think it’s mainly because you’re not using `animate` the way it should be used. For a start, the way you’re trying to increment `time` won’t work as you expect - the `do {...} while (...)` loop will just run as fast as possible without updating the screen.

Comment: `animate` is a callback that runs on each animation frame, so it shouldn’t be resetting `camera.lookAt`, adding event handlers etc.

Setting event handlers inside `if (...)` is very peculiar! Instead, try adding the event handlers outside of `animate`. 

Clicking the buttons should change the initial variables, then `animate` should increment the value of `time` and re-render.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Oh I see now you’re not adding event handlers but calling `onclick` which... is still quite confusing tbh!

Comment: I still think an invisible target might be the way to go, but this fiddle is not a good starting point. Maybe go back to the first fiddle you showed me and add an invisible target to that. 

As for animating / tweening it between the centres, you could use `gsap.to` for that rather than coding your own tween

Comment: Thank you for your help! I actually managed to get the desired animation by tweaking the coordinates in my first fiddle. This is the result(with only 3 geometries for simplification). https://jsfiddle.net/g5jneukp/92/

Comment: Great! I'm very glad to have helped. By the way, I intended to answer with a single comment but I kept hitting Enter, expecting a new line, and accidentally submitting before it was finished. I think in future I’ll write my response in a text editor then paste it in!